# "undefined" response and responseText from PHP file when using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I have a form written in html, some AJAX code and a PHP file which emails form's info to website's admin. The problem is, when I inspect the code by "console" tab in FireBug addon, everything is as I expect. The response is "OK My Friend" (As it should be in the case which email has been sent successfully). But when I want to see the exact `response` or `responseText` by these 2 lines :  `alert(this.responseText);` and `alert(this.response);` the opened alert window says : "undefined" in both cases. I mean the PHP file is sending response correctly and FireBug proves it. But I can't get the response by `this.response` or `this.responseText`. What's the problem in your opinion? I've checked possible duplicates of my question but none of them could help. 
 Here is my complete code : 
 PHP :

```
<?php
$to = "a@example.com";
$sendersName = $_POST[ 'name' ];
$sendersEmail = $_POST[ 'email' ];
$message = "Name : " . $sendersName . "\n";
$message .= "Email : " . $sendersEmail . "\n";
$message .= "Message : " . $_POST[ 'message' ] . "\n";
$header = "From:b@example.com \r\n";
$header .= "Cc:c@example.com \r\n";
$header .= "Bcc:d@example.com \r\n";
$result = mail( $to, "ارسال پیام به وبسایت تیام نت", $message, $header );
if ( $result == true ) {
    echo( "OK My Friend" );
} else {
    echo( "email not sent" );
}
?>
```

HTML Form :

```
    <div class="col-sm-5" id="contact_form">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">نام و نام خانوادگی</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید." id="name">
      <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">وارد نمودن نام و نام خانوادگی اجباری است.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">ایمیل</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="آدرس ایمیل خود را وارد کنید." id="email">
      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">وارد نمودن ایمیل اجباری است.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">پیام</label>
      <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="پیام خود را بنویسید." id="message">
      <label class="error" for="message" id="message_error">وارد نمودن پیام اجباری است.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ارسال" id="submit" class="center-block btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

AJAX :

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.error').hide();
    $("input#submit").click(function () {
        // validate and process form here

        $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name === "") {
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
        }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email === "") {
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }
        var message = $("input#message").val();
        if (message === "") {
            $("label#message_error").show();
            $("input#message").focus();
            return false;
        }
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendMessage.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                alert(this.responseText);
                alert(this.response);
                if (this.responseText === "OK My Friend") {
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>پیام شما ثبت شد!</h2>")
                        .append("<p>همکاران ما به زودی با شما تماس خواهند گرفت.</p>")
                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn(1500, function () {
                            $('#message').append("OK");
                        });
                } else {
                    //$('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    //$('#message').html(this.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.responseText` and `this.response` are never defined in your javascript and will thrown an undefined error in the console. To get the data from the server you have to change the `success: function` to

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data); // the response from the server
```

Comment: Exactly, undefined usually means there is an error in client side javascript. I had copied some code from a tutorial and they referenced event.target instead of this. which caused "undefined" error for me.